# Try to match string by regex into 3 part, but the third one is usually included in the 2nd group

Tags: python, regex

The project I recently work on is related to regex.
There is a long string consists of a few substring that I care of and this substring are directly or indirectly connected by empty string or some other string. 
The substring are consist of 3 groups, The first part is one of the following 3 letters (Glc|Gal|Man|Fuc), the second part is a not-fixed length of [a-zA-Z0-9] and the third part is "a" or "b". The tricky thing is the second part and third part are omitted sometime.
If I use greedy match, the last a and b are included to the second group. However, if I use lazy match, there will be missing character for the second part.

A few expected example:

```
Glc -> (Glc)(None)(None)
GlcF42x -> (Glc)(F42x)(None)
GlcF4ds2dsa2xa -> (Glc)(F4ds2dsa2x)(a)
Glcb -> (Glc)(None)(b)
```

And all this substring are parts from a longer string.
Like:  `"sklaja**Glc**someotherstring**GlcF42x**hmmmm**GlcF4ds2dsa2xa**lol**Glcb**dsadas"`

Any suggestion would be great.
Preferred in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about dividing it into 2 steps?
On step 1 you get 1st part (Glc|Gal|Man|Fuc) and the rest.
On step 2 you try to recognize if you can get [a,b] from the end:

GlcF4ds2dsa2xa:

```
>>> step1 = re.match('(Glc|Gal|Man|Fuc)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'GlcF4ds2dsa2xa')
>>> step1
<re.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='GlcF4ds2dsa2xa'>
>>> step1.group(1)
'Glc'
>>> step1.group(2)
'F4ds2dsa2xa'
>>> sub1 = step1.group(2)
>>> step2 = re.match('([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a,b]+)', sub1)
>>> step2
<re.Match object; span=(0, 11), match='F4ds2dsa2xa'>
>>> step2.group(1)
'F4ds2dsa2x'
>>> step2.group(2)
'a'
>>> ans = [step1.group(1), step2.group(1), step2.group(2)]
>>> ans
['Glc', 'F4ds2dsa2x', 'a']
```

GlcF42x:

```
>>> step1 = re.match('(Glc|Gal|Man|Fuc)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 'GlcF42x')
>>> step1
<re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='GlcF42x'>
>>> step1.group(1)
'Glc'
>>> step1.group(2)
'F42x'
>>> sub1 = step1.group(2)
>>> step2 = re.match('([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a,b]+)', sub1)
>>> step2
>>> step2 is None
True
>>>
```

Now you know that second match didn't succeed, so you can process it as two parts only.

To sum up, if only you are sure that possible 3rd part is "a" or "b", and this letters cannot occur on the end of 2nd part of the string, my sollution should help.

Comment: Yeah I've thought about that. The problem is existing infrastructure would expect I only changes regex pattern to accomplish that. Your solution definitely work. It is just I might need to change other place in the code. Thanks!

Comment: Can you upvote my answer please, if you found it useful?

Comment: Actually I upvoted, but it is not registered because I don’t have 15 score. Anyway thanks!